# pushwoosh & phonegao integration

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

I built an IOS application on phonegap. 
I am sending push notifications from pushwoosh - 
the problem is that pushwoosh need certificate for push notification, and phonegap need production certificate, 
Did someone solved that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Just use production push certificate for Pushwoosh and production mobileprovision and codesigning certificate for Phonegap.